# How to use ef6.exe

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm a newbie in entity framework. I have seen examples of using migrate.exe or `enable-migration` etc.

But migrate.exe does not exist any more. I explored the web and found that ef6.exe replaced the old migrate.exe

so I tried

```
ef6 -contexttypename musicstoredatacontext
ef6 -context musicstoredatacontext
```

nothing worked

I cannot find further support/documentation regarding the migration commands. and i'm new to migration.

Can somebody give me some hint how to work on it?

Answer (score 8):

"If you execute `Update-Database -Verbose` inside Visual Studio's Package Manager Console, it will show you the call it uses to ef.exe to apply migrations." [-Brice Lambson](https://github.com/bricelam)

It will be something like:

```
<PATH_TO_EXE>\ef6.exe database update --connection-string "<CONNECTION_STRING>" --connection-provider System.Data.SqlClient --verbose --no-color --prefix-output --assembly <PATH_TO_DLL> --project-dir <PATH_TO_PROJECT_DIR> --language C# --data-dir <PATH_TO_APP_DATA> --root-namespace <NAMESPACE> --config <PATH_TO_WEB_CONFIG>
```

Some of the arguments above can be omitted.

You can use the same strategy to determine how to create a migration (`Add-Migration`) with `ef6.exe`.

SOURCE: https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/1365#issuecomment-540067758

Comment: I was trying to find how to update the database from an external script and this verbose switch showed me what is being called every time i run a command from package manager console, thanks

Answer (score 4):

use the command help to get the docs

```
ef6 --help
```

or

```
ef6.exe migrations --help
```

Answer (score -1):

I succeeded in adding migration by updating powershell and use `add-migration initial` command

Reference can be found here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet

Comment: this belongs to EF Core (which has the cli support u mentioned), but not old EF6 that requires you to use the ef6.exe inside the nuget package folder or the Package Manager Console inside Visual Studio